# NullReferenceException on method call C#

Tags: c#, oop, class, nullreferenceexception

I have the following code:

```
DataGridModel[] raport = new DataGridModel[100];
... // more code here, nothing relevant
raport[i].populate(param1,param2); // NullReferenceException occurs here
```

My `DataGridModel` class has an empty constructor, so nothing is really done there.

When I watch the `raport` variable, it contains 100 times `null`, but why? Cause I initialized it with `new DataGridModel[100]`.

If I lose the array of objects in the first line (so only 1 instance), the code works great.

I don't get it why they are null. Any help?

Comment: Did you mean `raport[x].populate(param1, param2)`?

Comment: @kendfrey Yes, that's the way I have it in my code, I just copied it wrong :) Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You initialized it with `new DataGridModel[100]`, which creates an instance — but it's an instance of an array that contains 100 `null` elements.

I'm not sure what you mean by `raport.populate` - I suppose it's an extension method? - but here's how you can solve your problem:

```
DataGridModel[] raport = new DataGridModel[100];

for(int i = 0; i < raport.Length; i++) {
    raport[i] = new DataGridModel();
}

// ...

raport.populate(param1, param2);
```

Comment: Great stuff. I should have known that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new array of a reference type, you are only allocating an array of *references* to the type. So, you have 100 null references to `DataGridModel`.

You would need to iterate through the array and instantiate `DataGridModel`s.

Answer (score 1):

```
DataGridModel[] raport = new DataGridModel[100];
```

This initializes an array just saying "it will have 100 items", nothing more. You have to manually call the constuctor of each element:

```
for(int i = 0; i < raport.Length; i++)
    raport[i] = new DataGridModel();
```

Answer (score 1):

`new DataGridModel[100]` creates an array with space for 100 references to `DataGridModel` objects.

You still need to create these objects.